# IIS as a reverse proxy for a server with many ports

Tags: linux, windows, iis, reverse-proxy, pbx

I have a Windows Server 2016 machine with sales & accountant software running on it.

I want to deploy a telephony PBX server, running inside a linux Virtual Machine 
(via VMware). It's running on internal IP address 192.168.129.58. I want to set up a client software to connect to it like **'pbx.mysite.com'**

I know how to expose a website through a reverse proxy (on port 80).
But this VM need to be able to connect for a range of ports, e.g. 5060 for signalization and 100000-100200 for VoiceIP.

Is it possible to make a reverse proxy for Linux VM inside my Windows Server with many listening ports and connect to it via domain name?

Comment: IIS only takes care of HTTP/HTTPS traffic, so it won't help if your Linux VM wants traffic for telephony.

Comment: @LexLi , hah, right after asking this question I found how you answer on it on IIS forum :) But can you please recommend good software for realisation of this idea (if possible).

Comment: Any commercial firewall/gateway product should be able to forward TCP/UDP packets for telephony. Google might show you some names and then you can talk to their presale teams. I am not sure if there is any open source alternatives, but that should also be searchable via Google.